# do math with concatenated variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This should be a syntax issue but I find very little info on the web.
say I have the following code

```
var screenW = $(window).width(); 
$('.megamenu:nth-child(1)').css({'opacity' : '0', 'left' : ''+ screenW +'px'});
```

It works great but how do I multiply the concatenated variable screenW by number such as 0, 1, 2, 3 or -1, -2, -3

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmzMqe

Comment: ok I need more insight from you guys... so using (screenW) is the same as using '+ screenW+'?

Comment: You only have to use parentheses if you want the expression to be evaluated differently than it would be according to the order of operations. If you're just multiplying 2 numbers, you don't have to use `()`.

Comment: Or you can use parentheses to precisely indicate intent.

Comment: Thank you. Can you repose the answer so I can accept it?